# Cannot make json valid for recyclerview

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm trying to JSON using Gson and recyclerview. My JSON isnt completely valid. In my JSON, the food field has only one of the string quoted leaving the other unquoted. Kindly see my JSON below...

```
[

    {"quantity" = 2, 
    "price" = 15, 
    "food" = "Fried" Rice}, 

    {"quantity" = 2,
    "price" = 20,
    "food" = "Rice" and Stew}

    ]
```

You can see that Fried is in quotes and Rice isnt in quotes, likewise the same for Rice and Stew in the other too. Initially it was like this ...

```
[

    {quantity = 2, 
    price = 15, 
    food = Fried Rice}, 

    {quantity = 2,
    price = 20,
    food = Rice and Stew}

    ]
```

My activity class code...

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
        String listOfFood = extras.getString("foods");
        listOfFood = listOfFood.replaceAll("([\\w]+)[ ]*=", "\"$1\" ="); // to quote before = value
        listOfFood = listOfFood.replaceAll("=[ ]*([\\w@\\.]+)", "= \"$1\""); // to quote after = value, add special character as needed to the exclusion list in regex
        listOfFood = listOfFood.replaceAll("=[ ]*\"([\\d]+)\"", "= $1"); // to un-quote decimal value
        listOfFood = listOfFood.replaceAll("\"true\"", "true"); // to un-quote boolean
        listOfFood = listOfFood.replaceAll("\"false\"", "false"); // to un-quote boolean

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: "+listOfFood);

        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson mGson = builder.create();
        List<FoodOrder> posts = new ArrayList<FoodOrder>();
        posts = Arrays.asList(mGson.fromJson(listOfFood, FoodOrder[].class));
        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(FoodsOrderedActivity.this, posts);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

I need the food field that has Fried Rice to be inbetween quotes as one and the same for rice and stew or if theres a workaround, I would like to know.

Thank you

Comment: Just to make it easy for us to test your exact use-case, can you edit the question to include the exact value of `extras.getString("foods")`?

Comment: I think you're better off requiring that whoever passes you data to format it in a way that's easy to parse (like maybe they could just generate JSON for you from source data).  Trying to cobble something together with regular expressions is prone to error.  Data generally isn't meant to be dealt with this way when using code.

Comment: Note also the '=' need to be ':'.  You are better off separating the tasks of "preparing" data and "parsing" data.  Ultimately the data (json or not) must follow rules and if that is not the case then codifying a transform seems futile.

Comment: your JSON isn't completely valid. So it not a JSON, and you would not call it a JSON :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on your code. (Try to convert `listOfFood` to JSON )
I modify 2 lines of your code as bellow

```java
        listOfFood = listOfFood.replaceAll("(\\s*)([^{,\\s]+)(\\s*)=","$1\"$2\"$3:"); // to quote before = value and replace = by :
        listOfFood = listOfFood.replaceAll("(:\\s*)([^\\s,{}](\\s*[^\\s,{}]+)*)", "$1\"$2\""); // to quote after = value (= now became :)
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked like magic, i changed my first replace all code with what you gave me. Thank you am grateful

Comment: Another note that the pattern \d+ matches positive integer only. It will not match negative and none integer like `-123` and `123.456`.  To cover there cases: `listOfFood = listOfFood.replaceAll("(:\\s*)\"(-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)\"", "$1$2"); // to un-quote decimal value`

Answer (score 0):

The json structure should look like as below
[
{
"Key1" : "value1",
"Key2" : "value2",
},
{
"Key1" : "value1",
"Key2" : "value2",
}

]

Answer (score 0):

The json structure should be like this :

[{"quantity" : 2, 
    "price" : 15, 
    "food" : "Fried Rice"}, 
    {"quantity" : 2,
    "price" : 20,
    "food" : "Rice and Stew"}]